# Kubuntu switch to headphone when connected

Tags: sound, alsa, hdmi, headphones

I have installed Kubuntu 14.04.2 using the 3.19.6 kernel on an Asus Chromebox.

When I am in desktop mode, I couldn't hear any sounds.

This is a list of the devices:

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****

card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]

Subdevices: 0/1

Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]

Subdevices: 1/1

Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]

Subdevices: 1/1

Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC283 Analog [ALC283 Analog]

Subdevices: 1/1

Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

I fixed it by updating `/.asoundrc` so the default would be the HDMI output.

pcm.!default {

```
type hw

card 0

device 3
```

}

There is also the device ALC283 Analog (for headphones).
If I set the `.asoundrc` to this device, I hear through the headphones.

Now I would like to configure this such that whenever headphones are plugged in, the default would be ALC283 Analog device and otherwise the HDMI device. I figure if the default would change it would affect Kodi as well.

I wanted to fix it by using Pulseaudio, but when try to install it, I get:

```
package pulseaudio has no installation candidate.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about configuring `.asoundrc` but what I *can* tell you is that you should probably run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
```

In order to properly install Pulseaudio.

Comment: The error: package pulseaudio has no installation candidate is after I ran update